# Encrypt Spring Boot Rest Api Query Param

Tags: java, rest, encryption, aes

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but none of them are answering my question, So please don't mark this as duplicate.

I need to encrypt my parameters in rest API using AES.
I have created 2 APIs, for encryption and decryption.

```
import AesTest;
    import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;  
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.net.URLDecoder;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class BarcodeApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BarcodeApplication.class, args);
}

@GetMapping(value = "encrypt")
public String encrypt(@RequestParam BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "this is test") String text, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "200") String width, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "200") String height, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("barcodeFormat = " + barcodeFormat);
    System.out.println("text = " + text);
    System.out.println("width = " + width);
    System.out.println("height = " + height);
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    String encryptQuery = AesTest.encrypt(barcodeFormat.toString() + "&" + text + "&" + width + "&" + height);
    String urlEncodedData = URLEncoder.encode(encryptQuery, "UTF-8");
    return urlEncodedData;
}

@RequestMapping(path = "barcode/{query}")
public String getMessage(@PathVariable("query") String query, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String decryptQuery = AesTest.decrypt(query);
    String urlEncodedData = URLDecoder.decode(decryptQuery, "UTF-8");
    String[] queryArr = urlEncodedData.split("&");
    BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.valueOf(queryArr[0]);
    String text = queryArr[1];
    String width = queryArr[2];
    String height = queryArr[3];
    System.out.println("barcodeFormat = " + barcodeFormat);
    System.out.println("text = " + text);
    System.out.println("width = " + width);
    System.out.println("height = " + height);
    return null;
}
```

}`

Below is my AesTest File

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class AesTest {
    private static final String secretKey = "aesEncryptionKeyasdfghjk";
    private static final String initVector = "encryptionIntVec";

public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));
        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

if I am using http://localhost:8080/encrypt?text=**test**&height=50&barcodeFormat=CODE_128&width=200

it returns me 9mXpav2uRPRsNufSRpj1aXiD5sBVgmjFoyst8cQp%2Bms%3D.

passing this value in 2nd API http://localhost:8080/barcode/9mXpav2uRPRsNufSRpj1aXiD5sBVgmjFoyst8cQp%2Bms%3D is working perfectly fine.

but if I change the value of 1st API ie, http://localhost:8080/encrypt?text=**testshri**&height=50&barcodeFormat=CODE_128&width=200

it returns Js%2Butdm9mS9jxSNBbvHeCJaKv7TqrtImTU%2FqcDWaSo8%3D.

passing this value in 2nd API returns HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request.

Changing **text** in query param is giving different results.
What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Well whats causing the 400 Bad Request?

Comment: That value will need to be URL encoded because % signs are not URL safe

Comment: Also you should not be passing sensitive material in a url... that should always be in a request body

Comment: Hi @RobOhRob, I have URL encoded it, in encrypt method.
String urlEncodedData = URLEncoder.encode(encryptQuery, "UTF-8");
and % is present in 1st request as well, but its working fine.

Comment: Finding out why the BadRequest is being thrown will probably lead you to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the parameter you pass because it contains the ** `%` ** character which might corrupt the request url. It is therefore necessary to encode the data before using it in the URL and then to decode it during the retrieval.

Here is an example you can follow for that:

=== ENCODE :

```
private String encodeValue(String value) {
    return URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
}

@Test
public void givenRequestParam_whenUTF8Scheme_thenEncode() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> requestParams = new HashMap<>();
    requestParams.put("key1", "value 1");
    requestParams.put("key2", "value@!$2");
    requestParams.put("key3", "value%3");

    String encodedURL = requestParams.keySet().stream()
      .map(key -> key + "=" + encodeValue(requestParams.get(key)))
      .collect(joining("&", "http://www.baeldung.com?", ""));

    assertThat(testUrl, is(encodedURL));
}
```

=== DECODE :

```
private String decode(String value) {
    return URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
}

@Test
public void givenRequestParam_whenUTF8Scheme_thenDecodeRequestParams() {
    URI uri = new URI(testUrl);

    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    String host = uri.getHost();
    String query = uri.getRawQuery();

    String decodedQuery = Arrays.stream(query.split("&"))
        .map(param -> param.split("=")[0] + "=" + decode(param.split("=")[1]))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

    assertEquals("http://www.baeldung.com?key1=value 1&key2=value@!$2&key3=value%3",
        scheme + "://" + host + "?" + decodedQuery);
}
```

You can check out [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-url-encoding-decoding), which explains the concept in more detail.